# Python 3: How to search for and retrieve all lists that make up a Dictionary if they contain a specific string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary with the following keys and values:

```
Pasta : [['Tomato', 'hot'], ['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold'],
        ['Cheese','hot']]
Cookies : [['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot']]
Salad : [['Mushrooms', 'Lettuce', 'cold'], ['Lettuce', 'Fruits', 'cold']]
```

Say for each key I want to keep all of the values that contain the string 'hot', to get:

```
Pasta : [['Tomato', 'hot'], ['Cheese','hot']]
Cookies : [['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot']]
Salad : []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{key: [value for value in values if 'hot' in value] for (key, values) in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: You could actually check your code before posting it.

Comment: Sorry have it changed

Answer (score 2):

```
dictionary = { k : [ x for x in v if "hot" in x ] for k, v in dictionary.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#create function to get hot or cold menu items
def get_menu(dictionary,temp):
    temp_dict = {}
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        temp_dict[k] = []
        for sl in v:
            if temp in sl:
                temp_dict[k].append(sl)
    return temp_dict

menu = {'Pasta' : [['Tomato', 'hot'],['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold'],['Cheese','hot']],
     'Cookies' : [['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot']],
     'Salad' : [['Mushrooms', 'Lettuce', 'cold'], ['Lettuce', 'Fruits', 'cold']]}
#get hot menu items
hot_menu = get_menu(menu,"hot")
#get cold menu items
cold_menu = get_menu(menu,"cold")

#print results
print ("\n\n**** Hot Menu ****")
for key,value in hot_menu.items():
    if not value:
        continue
    print ("-"*25)
    print (key+": ")
    for sublist in value:
        sublist.remove("hot")
        print (" | "+" ".join(sublist))

print ("\n\n**** Cold Menu ****")
for key,value in cold_menu.items():
    if not value:
        continue
    print ("-"*25)
    print (key+": ")
    for sublist in value:
        sublist.remove("cold")
        print (" | "+" ".join(sublist))
```

Output:

```
**** Hot Menu ****
-------------------------
Cookies: 
 | Chocolate Nuts
 | Chocolate Pistachio
-------------------------
Pasta: 
 | Tomato
 | Cheese


**** Cold Menu ****
-------------------------
Pasta: 
 | Vegetables Lemon
-------------------------
Salad: 
 | Mushrooms Lettuce
 | Lettuce Fruits
```